# converting keras h5 to tfjs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am a total noob in pythona and with help of yt tuts made a keras h5 model with 97% accuracy.

Now I want to convert it to tfjs model to use it in my web app
for my first attempt

```
!tensorflowjs_converter \
  --input_format=keras \ h5jsmodelpath \outputpath
```

the following error popped after converting it into tfjs and loading it via js

1)The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2)The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().

I thought the way I used tfjs converter was wrong so I again used tfjs_converter with following code

```
!tensorflowjs_converter \
  --input_format=keras \
  --output_format=tfjs_graph_model \
  --output_node_names=dense_1/Identity \
  /content/WASTE8200X2359736.h5 \
  .
```

to obtain new tfjs model but this time loading it simply returns: "Model loading failed: and then entire model.json"

my js loading model code

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const handler = tf.io.fileSystem("tfjs_model\\content\\tfjs_model\\model.json");

const loadMyModel = async () => {
  try {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    console.log("Loaded model");

    // Get information about the layers
    model.layers.forEach((layer) => {
      console.log(`Layer Name: ${layer.name}`);
      console.log(`Input Shape: ${JSON.stringify(layer.inputShape)}`);
      console.log(`Output Shape: ${JSON.stringify(layer.outputShape)}`);
      console.log(`Number of Trainable Parameters: ${layer.countParams()}`);
      console.log("---------------------------");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Model loading failed:", error);
  }
};

loadMyModel();
```

gdrive links of my keras and both tfjs attempts:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O_u3GI5uWDGorpvo1PgYMwcexFKerCzz?usp=sharing

python notebook of orignal h5 model:https://github.com/Megahedron69/wasteSegregationmodel
so can someone help me convert this